# How to write text on image onfly in php?

Tags: php, image, gd, gd2

I want to make an image "onfly" with some text. Is it possible with php? I am trying with this one but no output is coming can anyone watch my code please?

```
function createCaptcha($string){
    $image = PATH_DIR . "blueprint/images/bg6.png";
    $text_vertical_position = 97;
    $font_size = 15;
    $color = '32a53d';
    Header ("Content-type: image/png");
    $color = convert_to_rgb($color);
    $info = GetImageSize($image);
    $width = $info[0];
    $height = $info[1];


    if (preg_match("/.gif/", $image)) {
        $image = imageCreateFromGif($image);
    } elseif (preg_match("/.png/", $image)) {
        $image = imageCreateFromPng($image);
    } elseif (preg_match("/.jpg/", $image)) {
        $image = imageCreateFromJpeg($image);
    } elseif (preg_match("/.jpeg/", $image)) {
        $image = imageCreateFromJpeg($image);
    }

    $imgcolor = ImageColorAllocate ($image, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2] );
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $start_length, $text_vertical_position,
                 $imgcolor, $font , $text);
    ImagePNG ($image);
    ImageDestroy ($image);
}
```

I am using codeigniter to make it.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you made a mistake in parameter of the function: `$string` not `$text`

```
 imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $start_length, $text_vertical_position,
      $imgcolor, $font, $string);
```

**PS.** If you make captcha - it would not reliable without any additional distortion of the image.

Why not to use ready-made solutions?

http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

http://www.captcha.ru/kcaptcha/

Comment: i have used kcaptcha it was easy